$L_p$ function and improper integral
I was studying at $L_p$ spaces, and I came across this thread (among others) : Show that the following function $f \in L_p$ if and only if $p=2$
Now, my question is : Why they analyze if the function is $L_p$ using Riemann Improper  integration, when the user is asking in terms of Lebesgue Measure? The fact that a Riemann improper integral is not finite implies that the Lebesgue integral is not finite?
Sorry if the question is too decontextualized or direct but I don’t understand that.
Thanks.

For a non-negative continuous function on $(a, b)$, $-\infty\leq a<b\leq+\infty$, its Lebesgue integral coincides with its improper Riemann integral: $$\int_{(a,b)} f(x) , \operatorname{Leb}(\mathrm{d}x) = \int_{a^+}^{b^-} f(x) , \mathrm{d}x.$$ This easily follows from the fact that, for a continuous function on a bounded closed interval, its Lebesgue integral and Riemann integral coincide.

@SangchulLee I was aware of that in the case of a type I improper integral. You apply monotone or dominated convergence theorem. In the case of type II improper, how you justify it?

You can still use the monotone/dominated convergence theorem. For example, if $$f:[a,b]\setminus{c}\to[0,\infty),$$ with $a<c<b$, is continuous, then $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x),\mathrm{d}x
=\lim_{\substack{c_L\to c^- \ c_R \to c^+}}\int_{a}^{c_L}f+\int_{c_R}^{b}f
=\lim_{\substack{c_L\to c^- \ c_R \to c^+}}\int_{[a,b]}f\cdot\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]\setminus(c_L,c_R)}
=\ldots$$

@SangchulLee Thanks. What would you choose as $f_n$ in that example you mention?

You can choose any subsequence of the net $(c_L,c_R)\to(c^-,c^+)$ and then set $f_n$ as the corresponding integrand. If the limit exists and the limiting value is independent of the choice of subsequence, then (and only in that case) the original limit as $(c_L,c_R)\to(c^-,c^+)$ exists.
